# Re-render (or animate) chart.js chart on transition within deck.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2, deck.js

I've made a deck.js slideshow and one of the slides has a chart.js piechart in it.

I'm trying to get the piechart to animate eachtime its slide is transitioned too. It currently only animates the first time it is transitioned to after a browser refresh.

I've tried adding the deck.events.js extension and using `chart.update()`, but it says the chart is not defined. Without the `deck.becameCurrent` snippet, the chart shows, and with the snippet the `console.log` works.

How do i get the deck.event to recognise the chart instance?

Is `chart.update()` the correct method to trigger the initial animations here?

```
    <body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js'></script>
<script src='{% static "vendor/deckjs/core/deck.core.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "vendor/deckjs/extensions/events/deck.events.js" %}'>


        <div class="deck-container">
            <section class="slide" id="pie">
                <script>
                var ctx1 = $("#NestedChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
                    type: 'doughnut',
                    data: {
                        labels: [1,2,3,4,5],        
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [10,89,4,34,33],
                        },
                        options: {
                            animation: {
                                duration:2000
                    },
            });
            })
                </script>

                <div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width:500px" class='col-sm-6'>
                    <canvas style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" id="NestedChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                </div>
           </section>
       </div>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $.deck('.slide', {countNested: false});

        $("#pie").bind('deck.becameCurrent', function(ev, direction) {
            console.log("test chart update");
            myChart1.update();
         });
      });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by moving the code that defines the chart to be within the `becameCurrent` event function:

```
 $(function() {
    $.deck('.slide', {countNested: false});
    $.deck('showGoTo');
    $("#pie").bind('deck.becameCurrent', function(ev, direction) {
        const ctx1 = $("#NestedChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        const myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {.....
```

This then re-renders the chart on each transition. An if loop allows it to only animate on a forward transition.
Putting the myChart1 variable declaration anywhere else initialises the chart the first time, but  `myChart1.render()` or `myChart1.reset().update()` within the becameCurrent() function still don't seem to do anything.